# How to generate switch statement skeleton with an enum

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement, generator

If have an enum in e.g. `Day` with `SunDay`, `MunDay`, etc. Is there an easy way to generate the `switch` statement as below ? There is so much to much by hand.

```
switch(day) {

     case SunDay :
            break;

     case MunDay :
            break;

     // and so on
}
```

Comment: That code should work.  So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "generate"?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: That code works.. Keep in mind that convention states your enum values should be uppercase.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA will offer to generate `switch` branches for an `enum` switch when I press Alt-Enter.

Comment: Ok, you're talking about code generation.  Well, there are lots of mechanisms for doing this, but they all of course depend on being able to define what you want the code to consist of (i.e. a procedure to follow for generating the code).  So; what do you want this code to consist of in practice?

Comment: maybe he is using old version of JDK

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse IDE, you can construct a empty switch, and Eclipse will give you an option called 'Add missing case statements' to automatically generate the switch. See the imagem below:

(Open the image in another window to see it better.)

[image]

Comment: What is I want only some of the enums e.g few months of a year.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
public class DaySwitchGenerator {
    public static void main(String...args) {
        System.out.println("switch(day) {");

        for (Day e : Day.values() ) {
            System.out.println("    case " + e.name() + " :");
            System.out.println("        break;");
        }

        System.out.println("}");
    }
}
```